# How can I reduce the number of return false in this Swift func

Tags: swift, function, return

I get the feeling all the "return false" statements in this function might be redundant. I encounter a similar scenario often. I would like to avoid the bloat of any extra code.

**Question: Is there a way to reduce the quantity of the "return false" statements and still have the function do the same thing?**

For context, I am trying to efficiently check an array of Int in UserDefaults to see if it contains a particular integer.

```
func isItemNumberInList(itemNumber : Int) -> Bool{

    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myList") != nil{
        if var myList : [Int] = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myList") as? [Int]{
            if myList.index(of: itemNumber) != nil {
                return true
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }else{
        return false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There is* indeed *a way*

```
func isDockNumberInList(dockNumber : Int) -> Bool {
    guard let myList = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myList") as? [Int],
        myList.contains(dockNumber) else { return false }
    return true
}
```

or

```
func isDockNumberInList(dockNumber : Int) -> Bool {
    guard let myList = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myList") as? [Int] else { return false }
    return myList.contains(dockNumber)
}
```

Comment: Aah, so the guard statement handles any combination of problems in one fell swoop: whether the UserDefault exists, whether it's an [Int], if the value is in there.  I see you have used a comma to include several statements. That's cool. Based on your answer, I have found this helpful link: https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/
I have used guard statements in the past, but they were a bit different in earlier versions of Swift. Thank you for the help here. You have answered the question and helped to remove the many repeated return statements.

Comment: I edited the answer for a still better solution. By the way: It's worth it to read the Swift Language Guide.

Comment: Interesting that you included this within the guard statement: "myList.contains(dockNumber) else { return false }"  If/else logic within a single clause.  The latter example does seem cleaner, but it's an interesting thought.

Comment: If you don't need the index explicitly `contains` is preferable.

Comment: I don't need the index. So yes

Comment: @vadian I'm drinking the koolaid again: `return (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myList") as? [Int]).map{ $0.contains(dockNumber) } ?? false`

Comment: @Alexander I knew somebody would provide an one-liner ;)

Comment: And why not use `array(forKey:)` instead of `object(forKey:)`?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, why not? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to delete your first if statement, since it is completely redundant due to the fact that the conditional binding can only succeed if the value is non-nil. Then you can also merge the two inner if statement into one, since you only care whether both are true or not.

```
func isItemNumberInList(itemNumber : Int) -> Bool{
    if let myList = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myList") as? [Int], myList.index(of: itemNumber) != nil {
       return true
    } else {
        return false 
    }
}
```

The else statement can be omitted is well, since in case the if statement evaluates to true, the function will exit by returning true, so the `return false` expression can only be reached in case the if statement before evaluated to false.

```
func isItemNumberInList(itemNumber : Int) -> Bool{
    if let myList = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myList") as? [Int], myList.index(of: itemNumber) != nil {
       return true
    }
    return false 
}
```

Comment: I upvoted the answer because it helped me to see that among the answers given for this, whether using "guard" or "if" syntax, the real key seems to be using commas in "if/else" statements and not breaking them up.  That is one of the key optimizations I have learned from this. Thank you.

Comment: @JackAmoratis Using a comma here is appropriate for `if let`, not general `if` statements.

Comment: @rmaddy what do you think of above where one of the clauses is not let related. The second clause checks to see if the index is nil?  RE "if let myList = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myList") as? [Int], myList.index(of: itemNumber) != nil {"

Comment: @JackAmoratis Right. The statement starts off as `if let`. The comma separates that `if let` from the condition. If you simply want to check two conditions in an `if` (without the need of `if let`), then you would use `if expression1 && expression2`.

Comment: @JackAmoratis syntactically a comma can be used instead of && even in a "normal" if statement without optional binding. `let isTrue = true; if true, isTrue {}` works perfectly fine and evaluates to true

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for the tip regarding "&&."  Now my question is I just tried both forms such as: "if 1 == 1 , 2 == 2 { }" and then: "if 1 == 1 && 2 == 2 { }"  Which both work.  Is it simply good form, or is there a technical distinction between "," and "&&" in this scenario?

Comment: @JackAmoratis You really should post another question on this topic (if you can't find an existing one). Comments are not the place to discuss a completely separate topic.

Comment: @rmaddy I am going to avoid asking additional questions on your comments then, because you agree that your comments go beyond the original question - which makes my follow up on them go even further. By all means, feel free to open a private chat if you would like to continue discussing. Thanks again!